# Python Kivy не получается достучаться до переменной

Tags: python, kivy

Пытаюсь через функцию num_plus достучаться до переменной num, чтобы при каждом нажатии кнопки, он увеличивал значение на единицу, но, к сожалению, каждый раз при нажатии показывает, что он равен 0. Вот main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class MyW(BoxLayout):
    num = 0
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyW, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        s = Screen(name="Hello1")
        s.add_widget(Label(text="page1"))
        self.ids.sm.add_widget(s)

        s = Screen(name="Hello2")
        s.add_widget(Label(text="page2"))
        self.ids.sm.add_widget(s)

    def num_plus(self, number):
        number = number + 1

class e1App(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyW()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e1App().run()
```

А это e1.kv:

```
<MyW>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        id: buttons
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
    Button:
        on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'Hello1'; root.num_plus(root.num); print(root.num)
    Button:
        on_press: root.ids.sm.current = 'Hello2'; root.num_plus(root.num); print(root.num)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю есть ли для Kivy какие-то премудрости для работы с переменными, но код:

```
def num_plus(self, number):
    number = number + 1
```

Чисто питоничьи не будет работать как вы хотите, т.к. внутри функции вы просто создадите новую *локальную* переменную `number` и ей присвоите значение предыдущего `number` + 1.

Кст, странно выглядит у вас код с `root.num_plus(root.num);` -- зачем передавать поле объекта в его же метод? Давайте код упростим и заодно решим проблему.

---

Попробуйте сделать так:

Вместо:

```
def num_plus(self, number):
    number = number + 1
```

будет работа с самим полем `num`:

```
def num_plus(self):
    self.num += 1
```

И в `on_press` вызов `num_plus` станет таким:

```
root.num_plus();
```

Comment: Всё заработало!